# Where is the name resolution performed for local addresses?

Tags: dns

For local addresses like: `http://some_local_host`, it is obvious that name resolution is not performed by querying DNS servers. But how and where is it performed then? How does my computer obtain the information that it needs to connect to `192.168.2.56` when I type `http://some_local_host`?

Comment: "it is obvious that name resolution is not performed by querying DNS servers" - what makes you think that it is obvious? Did you look in the `hosts` file? What is your operating system?

Comment: Windows. The reason I thought it is obvious that there is no TLD named `some_local_host`. So had it looked DNS servers, I guess that they wouldn't return any result. I didn't yet look at the `hosts` file.

Comment: In addition to the LMHOSTS file, Windows also will lookup single-label names via NetBIOS broadcasts or query WINS servers if configured.  And it tries that way before trying DNS with appended search-list domains.